# "ps" command print error timestamp in container

Tags: docker, ps

I got a problem,in container ,when I execute ps command ,and print error future time stamp,but date command print right time;at localhost I execute ps command,print right timestamp

in container :

```
#date
Tue Nov  1 14:20:11 CST 2016

#ps uax
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  10416   660 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:00 init [3]
root        58  0.0  0.0  49332   544 ?        S    Nov08   0:00 supervising      syslog-ng
root        59  0.0  0.0  52512  2508 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:14 /sbin/syslog-ng
```

Comment: "Container"? What do you mean by that? Please elaborate, and possibly add tags.

Comment: I am using docker